# Navigation controller and no storyboards

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I am writing an app in Objective C. For this project I cannot use ARC or storyboards. It should have 6 views. Firstly, the navigation controller shall keep table view (it will contain some data passed in from an array). In the toolbar on the top once the item has been pressed the app should move to second view.

I know that I need to code that in my delegate file, but I a not quite sure what needs to be included. Those were the requirements.

In fact when I run my app it does not show that navigation controller which got table view as my entry view. In the settings I cannot find a checkbox in order to select it and make it an entry view.
Any suggestions?
Best regards

Comment: It's not clear enough from your question what you're looking for.

Comment: There has been given initial requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to use `UITabBarController`

Firsts Create all object of `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate.h` file  and use following method of `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ]];

    self.viewCon=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.viewCon.title=@"First View";

    self.fView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.FnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.fView];
    self.FnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.fView.title=@"Secound View";

    self.sView=[[SecoundViewController alloc] init];
    self.SnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.sView];
    self.SnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.sView.title=@"Third View";
    .
    .
    // create UIViewController and UINavigationController As you need 
    .
    .
    .
    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia.gif"];
    self.tbItem1=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First Page" image:img1 tag:1];
    self.viewCon.tabBarItem=self.tbItem1;

    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon.gif"];
    self.tbItem2=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Secound Page" image:img2 tag:2];
    self.fView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem2;

    UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.png"];
    self.tbItem3=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third Page" image:img3 tag:3];
    self.sView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem3;

    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.FnavCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.SnavCon];


    self.tbCon=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tbCon.viewControllers=viewArr;

    [self.window addSubview:tbCon.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How can you know that UITabBarController is the best thing to use? It's not very clear what the question is trying to do.